# Check if block rendered and displayed on the current page

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, magento-1, render

Is there any way I can check if a block is displayed on the current page?

I have a block `my.banner` with simple image. This block is added to the left sidebar on many different types of pages, e.g. on category pages, on custom CMS pages etc.

```
<default>
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="mymodule/header" name="my_header" template="header.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
<cms_page>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="mymodule/banner" name="my.banner" template="banner.phtml" />
    </reference>
</cms_page>
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="mymodule/banner" name="my.banner" template="banner.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
...
```

Then, in another block `my_header` in the header I need to programmatically check if `my.banner` block will be actually displayed on the current page. **If it's not displayed**, then in the header I need to display additional info for customers.

I can check if the `my.banner` exists in the layout:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('my.banner');
if ($block !== false)
{
    //...banner exists
}
```

But this is not a solution, because the problem is that admin can any time **disable the left sidebar** (e.g. on selected category page). And if the left sidebar was removed, then `my.banner` will not be displayed even if it's added to the sidebar in layout.

1. So is there any way I can check if `my.banner` block will be actually rendered and displayed on the page?
2. And if it's possible in Magento 1, what is equivalent in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

Not in the way you want it. The problem is that at the time the header is rendered, you can't know if another block *will* be rendered at a later point. As you already noticed, there are other factors besides the block being part of the layout hierarchy, for example:

- will `getChildHtml()` of the parent block be called?
- is module output disabled?
- is the block dynamically removed somewhere between rendering of the head and rendering of the blocks parent?
- will the parent even be rendered?

So you will need some trickery. A possible workaround is to make the check in another block that is rendered *after* your block, for example as child of `before_body_end` and then move your alternative content to the header with JavaScript.

For this to work you must also make a change in your banner block because by default there is no flag that says "the block was rendered".

In Magento 1, you can use the `_afterToHtml()` method for that:

```
protected function _afterToHtml()
{
    $this->setData('i_was_rendered', true);
}
```

Then later you can check it like this:

```
if (! $layout->getBlock('my.banner')->getData('i_was_rendered_')) {
}
```