# Check if current layout has another block by name PHP - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout

I want to add classes to two elements on the page specifically if two or one other element is on the page, so in the phtml I will have to check if those elements are included in the layout.

How can this be done?

Comment: You should read more: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107634/check-if-block-rendered-and-displayed-on-the-current-page